# Next-Word Prediction Engines - which branch of AI do they belong

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, prediction, n-gram

Next-word prediction or phrase-prediction engines used in modern keyboards of mobiles and tablets, like swift key & XT9, which predict the next word the user is going to type based on some pre-defined or dynamic corpus, based on n-grams (maximum frequency of last typed 2-3 words plus the current word) based language models (Markov Model).

What I think is that these engines/algos are a part of AI/NLP. But what I am not sure about is what specific branch of AI/NLP they belong to.
Is it machine learning ? Is it data science ? Is it big data ? Is it Computing Intelligence ? Is it decision-making ? Is it data-mining ? Or statistical pattern recognition/ predictive analytics/ Supervised learning/ Unsupervised learning ? Or all/many of these or something else ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They tend to be called [language models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_model), and I'd say it's a branch of natural language processing.

I'd say that it is machine learning, good models will tend to use big data, and it is a supervised learning problem, though with a much different flavor than typical textbook supervised learning problems.

Comment: Algorithmtically, it's a supervised problem, but data comes with its own labels :)

Comment: Thanks @rrenaud for the succint explanation.

Comment: Even though the answer is old and accepted, I just wanted to comment that "next word prediction" is different from "language models" in common usage since "language models" take a string as input and produce its probability whereas "next word prediction" models produce the most probable next word as output. The data structures needed would be different even if the statistics used are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Word prediction techniques are well-established methods in the
field of AAC (Augmentative and Alternative Communication)
that are frequently used as communication aids for people with
disabilities

1) accelerate the writing;
2) reduce the effort needed to type;
3) suggest the correct word (no misspellings)

source: http://medialab.di.unipi.it/web/Language+Intelligence/Prediction.pdf>